# ADB devices command shows the empty list with my Galaxy S10 5G

Tags: android, adb, galaxy

I want to flash some image to my Galaxy S10 5G.
So I install samsung driver [according to this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73sJWh6yrsY). And I unlock my bootloader. command`adb devices` works if phone is booted on normal mode. However `adb devices` doesn't show any devices if I boot my galaxy S10 5G on download mode using `adb reboot bootloader` And I check if the phone is adb sideload, it can recognize. Only fastboot mode is cannot be recognized.

Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got the answer.
After the command `adb reboot bootloader`
You should check whether device is connected or not by command `fastboot devices` My question was quite dumb. Thanks all.